# Comparing pandas columns with long list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose we have a long list of tuples consisting of coordinates:

```
coords = 
[(61.0, 73, 94.0, 110.0),
(61.0, 110.0, 94.0, 148.0), 
(61.0, 148.0, 94.0, 202.0), 
(61.0, 202.0, 94.0, 241.0).......]
```

Our dataframe has mutiple columns including 'left, top, left1, top1' which correspond to coordinates.

```
    left    top     left1   top1
0   398     57.0    588     86
1   335     122.0   644     145
2   414     150.0   435     167
3   435     150.0   444     164
4   444     150.0   571     167
...     ...     ...     ...     ...
```

I'm wanting to check which rows fall within these coordinates. I'm currently doing this one tuple at a time as shown below but this is very slow.

```
for coord in coords:
    result = df.loc[(df['left']>(coord[0])) &
                    (df['left1']<=(coord[2])) & 
                    (df['top1']>(coord[1])) & 
                    (df['top']<(coord[3]))]
```

Is there a quicker way to do this?

Many thanks to all contributors in advance!

Comment: How long is your dataframe/coords?

Comment: You may want to create dataframe of coordinates and use by-column comparison to create columns of bools and then apply & to the bool columns. You will get a column that consists of true or false values, can use it as an index.

Comment: Hi @QuangHoang - it varies but list of coords can be up to 1000 and dataframe up to 2000 rows. Overall, taking an average of  a couple of seconds to churn through this with each comparison about 3ms

Comment: Maybe `np.select` can be helpful here. Laptop's away from so couldn't post solid answer with `timeit` analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `numpy` broadcast

```
df=df.reindex(columns=['left','top1','left1','top'])
a=np.sign(df.values - np.array(coords)[:, None]) 
idx=np.any(np.all(np.sign(a)==np.array([1,1,-1,-1]),2),0) |np.any(np.all(np.sign(a)==np.array([1,1,0,-1]),2),0)
idx
Out[237]: array([ True, False, False, False, False])

df_sub=df[idx]
```

---

For example

```
df
Out[231]: 
    left    top1  left1    top
0  10000  100000      0    0.0
1    335     145    644  122.0
2    414     167    435  150.0
3    435     164    444  150.0
4    444     167    571  150.0
```

Your out put

```
for coord in coords:
    result = df.loc[(df['left']>(coord[0])) &
                    (df['left1']<=(coord[2])) & 
                    (df['top1']>(coord[1]))
                    & 
                    (df['top']<(coord[3]))]

result
Out[228]: 
    left  top  left1    top1
0  10000  0.0      0  100000
```

---

My out put

```
df_sub = df[idx]
print(df_sub)
    left    top1  left1  top
0  10000  100000      0  0.0
```

Comment: May I know the reason why downvote ? would you like explain the part I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Hi @YOBEN, thanks that's significantly faster! I've marked as correct. Could you help explain the idx one-liner so I can better understand how that works?

Comment: @lawson we compared the each row of df with coords , after we get the sub, to match the output we need at least one sub-row contain all True, then after that if each column contain any of True , we should pick it up. np.sign, is convert the negative positive and 0 to -1, 1,0

Comment: thanks - that makes sense. This wasn't part of the original question but how would we see which of the tuples of coordinates matched with a corresponding dataframe value?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is a cross join, followed by a filter:

```
coord_df = pd.DataFrame(coords, columns=['left', 'top', 'left1', 'top1'])

# We need to assign dummies for the cross join
coord_df['dummy'] = 1
df['dummy'] = 1

both_rects = df.merge(coord_df, key='dummy', suffixes=('_inner', '_outer'))
```

Then you're back to filtering by your original expression:

```
rects_within = both_rects.loc[(both_rects.left_inner > both_rects.left_outer) &
                              (both_rects.top_inner > both_rects.left_outer) &
                              (both_rects.left1_inner <= both_rects.left1_outer) &
                              (both_rects.top1_inner <= both_rects.top1_outer)]
```